# Execute javascript in a Link

Tags: javascript

How can I execute

```
 <script>alert("abc")</script>
```

in a link?

The idea is to show a pop up saying abc when I execute the link in a web browser.

Comment: I'm afraid JS doesn't haves access to browsers UI elements.

Comment: Do you want the alert to show when the new page loads?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('abc')">clickme</a>
<!-- or -->
<a href="#" onclick="alert('abc'); return false;">clickme</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

function myFunction() {
   alert("abc");
   window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons javascript: inside browser address bar no more working (why? din't found reference for this). Anyhow you still run JavaScript and many other stuff in address bar.

Paste this into your browser address bar:

```
data:text/html,<script>alert(0);window.location="http://www.ehacking.net/2014/10/becoming-hacker-what-how-and-why.html";</script>
```

**Update** here is fully example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My Page</h1>

<a href='#' onclick="hack(1)">hack</a>

</body>
<script>
function hack(value)
{
if (value != 1) return true;
  var evilscript=JSON.stringify("data:text/html,<script>alert('you got hacked');window.location='https://www.facebook.com/';<" + "/" + "script>");
  window.location = JSON.parse(evilscript);
  return false;
}
</script>

</html>
```